# Svelte components does not react to variable changes

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a variable on a component and a function to change the value of that variable is exported from the component; that function is imported in another component to change the variable when it is triggered. The opened class should be added to the h1 element in the component.

#### Component.svelte

```
<script context="module">
    let active = false;
    
    export function ToggleColor() {
        active = !active;
        console.log(active)
    }
</script>

<h1 id="color" class:opened={active}>Hello</h1>

<style>
    #color {
        color: red
    }
    #color.opened {
        color: blue !important;
    }
</style>
```

The value of the variable is changed and logged in the console but the component (specifically adding and removing classes) does not react to it.

#### App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Component, {ToggleColor} from "./Component.svelte";
</script>

<Component />

<div on:click={ToggleColor}> click to change color </div>
```

Can a kind person tell me what I am getting wrong here, please. I have also created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/35bbbf6d8f4746f08915017f420caa72) for this issue. Any incoming assistance is greatly appreaciated. Thanks in advance. Disclaimer: I am extremely inexperienced at Svelte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `context="module"` script:

> A `<script>` tag with a `context="module"` attribute runs once when the module first evaluates, rather than for each component instance.
> Variables defined in `module` scripts are not reactive — reassigning them will not trigger a rerender even though the variable itself will update. For values shared between multiple components, consider using a store.

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-context-module)

Since there is only one instance of everything in the module script, you also would not be able to use multiple instances of the component: They all would share the same `active` value.

You could fix the code by properly using the instance script, though this requires that you use `bind:this` on the component to get a reference to the component instance:

```html
<!-- In component -->
<script>
    let active = false;
    export function toggleColor() { active = !active; }
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Usage -->
<script>
    import Component from "./Component.svelte";
    let component;
</script>

<Component bind:this={component} />
<button on:click={() => component.toggleColor()}>
    Click to change color
</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5f2b6cb91efb44ccb82d2dfaf847faf9?version=3.52.0)

This is not how you would usually do this, though. Instead, just expose the `active` value as a prop and update it from the outside:

```html
<!-- In component -->
<script>
    export let active = false;
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Usage -->
<script>
    import Component from "./Component.svelte";
    let active = false;
</script>

<Component {active} />
<button on:click={() => active = !active}>
    Click to change color
</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/99f9f179052a426cb6839214a7d52e09?version=3.52.0)

(By the way, you should *not* add click handlers to arbitrary elements, but use a `<button>` instead. This way it will be more accessible and e.g. trigger on enter when focused.)

Comment: Thanks for the exceptional answer. You are the kindest soul.